# Unable to get a generic ResponseEntity<T> where T is a generic class "SomeClass<SomeGenericType>"

Tags: java, spring, rest, generics, spring-mvc

Please help me to get a `ResponseEntity<T>` where `T` is itself a generic type. As I see it of now, this is not supported nowdays by spring RestTemplate. I'm using Spring MVC version 3.1.2

Here is my code, that I want to use:
Code:

```
ResponseEntity<CisResponse<CisResponseEntity>> res =
         this.restTemplate.postForEntity(
             this.rootURL, myRequestObj, CisResponse.class);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<CisResponse> to
ResponseEntity<CisResponse<CisResponseEntity>>
```

It's obvious error, but how I can workaround it today?

Than I do want to get my generic response type:

```
CisResponse<CisResponseEntity> myResponse= res.getBody();
CisResponseEntity entity = myResponse.getEntityFromResponse();
```

For now, I use this solution, with `postForObject()` and not `postForEntity()`:

```
CisResponse<CisResponseEntity> response = 
          this.restTemplate.postForObject(
               this.rootURL,myRequestObj, CisResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This was [a known issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7023). Now it's fixed with the introduction of `ParameterizedTypeReference`, which is a parameterized type that you explicitely **inherit** to supply type information at runtime. This is called a *super-type token*, and works around type erasure because subclasses (anoniymous in this case) keep the **type arguments of the generic supertype** at runtime.

However you can't use `postForObject`, because the API only supports [`exchange()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html):

```
ResponseEntity<CisResponse<CisResponseEntity>> res = template.exchange(
        rootUrl,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<CisResponse<CisResponseEntity>>() {});
```

Note that the last line demonstrates the idea of [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.it/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html): you don't supply the literal `CisResponse.class`, but an anonymous instantiation of the parameterized type `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`, which at runtime can be expected to extract subtype information. You can think of super type tokens as *hacks* for achieving `Foo<Bar<Baz>>.class`

BTW, in Java you don't need to prefix access to instance variable with `this`: if your object defines a `url` and `template` members, just access them with their simple name, and not by prefixing like you do `this.url` and `this.template`