# Using generic method for RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, generics

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter) **solution wasn't useful for me**, therefore this isn't a duplicate, it's a different question.. I'm asking another question because it might render a different solution than the linked post.

---

I'm trying to create a generic method to use `RestTemplate` from Spring, but the type is ignored, and my `Object` is not constructed correctly.

### **Generic Method:**

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> restGetRequest(String url, String ... params) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<T> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {};

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    return template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, type, params);
}
```

I'm trying to use this method for any `GetRequest` I might use inside my application, making the code smaller.

### **The Problem:**

When trying to retrieve the Object, it's type is not what was expected, and it came as normal `JSON` (just a `String`).

**Retrieving:**

```
String url;
ResponseEntity<MyType> apiResponse = restGetRequest(url);
```

`apiResponse` isn't of type `MyType` as I expected it to be. This way, my mapping isn't done correctly.

---

Is there a way to do this in Java, **without** creating new classes, nor passing a class as a parameter, nor extending any class? **Just using the generic type**?

Comment: No, that's exactly what that other post is telling you.