# How to use RestTemplate.exchange for different subclasses

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have an Abstract base class A, and 2 subclasses (B and C) inherit from A.

Now I am currently using RestTemplate exchange to retrieve a list of objects from a REST API endpoint. But those objects can be either B or C. How do I do this using RestTemplate? The following if my code

```
ResponseEntity<B> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                endpointURL,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<B>() {} );
```

Above is for B, but the responseEntity can be either B or C.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter/29547365#29547365

Comment: Use `A` as a response entity, Maybe, Also remember that RestTemblate is deprecated use `WebClient` instead https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html

Comment: @YouYou ahh, didnt know it was deprecated, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0):

If your `A` class is abstract `RestTemplate` won't be able to instantiate it. There are possible solutions:

- Make `A` not abstract. You will be able to get `A` instance as a response but all of the `B` and `C` specific fields will be missed.
- Use `String` or Jackson's `JsonNode` as a response type and then manually check the properties to make sure that response is `B` or `C` and create your `B`/`C` instance using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`.