# WebFlux WebClient with Generic Types

Tags: java, spring-webflux, servicenow, spring-webclient, servicenow-rest-api

I'm trying to make a Client Library with WebClient from Spring WebFlux.

Server return responses like this JSON:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "parent": "",
      "made_sla": "true",
      "watch_list": "",
      "upon_reject": "cancel",
      "sys_updated_on": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "approval_history": "",
      "number": "PRB0000050",
      "sys_updated_by": "glide.maint",
      "opened_by": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/glide.maint",
        "value": "glide.maint"
      },
      "user_input": "",
      "sys_created_on": "2016-01-19 04:51:19",
      "sys_domain": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
        "value": "global"
      },
      "state": "4",
      "sys_created_by": "glide.maint",
      "knowledge": "false",
      "order": "",
      "closed_at": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "cmdb_ci": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci/55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9",
        "value": "55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9"
      },
      "delivery_plan": "",
      "impact": "3",
      "active": "false",
      "work_notes_list": "",
      "business_service": "",
      "priority": "4",
      "sys_domain_path": "/",
      "time_worked": "",
      "expected_start": "",
      "rejection_goto": "",
      "opened_at": "2016-01-19 04:49:47",
      "business_duration": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "group_list": "",
      "work_end": "",
      "approval_set": "",
      "wf_activity": "",
      "work_notes": "",
      "short_description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "correlation_display": "",
      "delivery_task": "",
      "work_start": "",
      "assignment_group": "",
      "additional_assignee_list": "",
      "description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "calendar_duration": "1970-01-01 00:02:17",
      "close_notes": "updated firmware",
      "sys_class_name": "problem",
      "closed_by": "",
      "follow_up": "",
      "sys_id": "04ce72c9c0a8016600b5b7f75ac67b5b",
      "contact_type": "phone",
      "urgency": "3",
      "company": "",
      "reassignment_count": "",
      "activity_due": "",
      "assigned_to": "",
      "comments": "",
      "approval": "not requested",
      "sla_due": "",
      "comments_and_work_notes": "",
      "due_date": "",
      "sys_mod_count": "1",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "escalation": "0",
      "upon_approval": "proceed",
      "correlation_id": "",
      "location": ""
    },
    {
      "parent": "",
      "made_sla": "true",
      "watch_list": "",
      "upon_reject": "cancel",
      "sys_updated_on": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "approval_history": "",
      "number": "PRB0000050",
      "sys_updated_by": "glide.maint",
      "opened_by": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/glide.maint",
        "value": "glide.maint"
      },
      "user_input": "",
      "sys_created_on": "2016-01-19 04:51:19",
      "sys_domain": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
        "value": "global"
      },
      "state": "4",
      "sys_created_by": "glide.maint",
      "knowledge": "false",
      "order": "",
      "closed_at": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "cmdb_ci": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci/55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9",
        "value": "55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9"
      },
      "delivery_plan": "",
      "impact": "3",
      "active": "false",
      "work_notes_list": "",
      "business_service": "",
      "priority": "4",
      "sys_domain_path": "/",
      "time_worked": "",
      "expected_start": "",
      "rejection_goto": "",
      "opened_at": "2016-01-19 04:49:47",
      "business_duration": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "group_list": "",
      "work_end": "",
      "approval_set": "",
      "wf_activity": "",
      "work_notes": "",
      "short_description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "correlation_display": "",
      "delivery_task": "",
      "work_start": "",
      "assignment_group": "",
      "additional_assignee_list": "",
      "description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "calendar_duration": "1970-01-01 00:02:17",
      "close_notes": "updated firmware",
      "sys_class_name": "problem",
      "closed_by": "",
      "follow_up": "",
      "sys_id": "04ce72c9c0a8016600b5b7f75ac67b5b",
      "contact_type": "phone",
      "urgency": "3",
      "company": "",
      "reassignment_count": "",
      "activity_due": "",
      "assigned_to": "",
      "comments": "",
      "approval": "not requested",
      "sla_due": "",
      "comments_and_work_notes": "",
      "due_date": "",
      "sys_mod_count": "1",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "escalation": "0",
      "upon_approval": "proceed",
      "correlation_id": "",
      "location": ""
    },
    {
      "parent": "",
      "made_sla": "true",
      "watch_list": "",
      "upon_reject": "cancel",
      "sys_updated_on": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "approval_history": "",
      "number": "PRB0000050",
      "sys_updated_by": "glide.maint",
      "opened_by": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/glide.maint",
        "value": "glide.maint"
      },
      "user_input": "",
      "sys_created_on": "2016-01-19 04:51:19",
      "sys_domain": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
        "value": "global"
      },
      "state": "4",
      "sys_created_by": "glide.maint",
      "knowledge": "false",
      "order": "",
      "closed_at": "2016-01-19 04:52:04",
      "cmdb_ci": {
        "link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci/55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9",
        "value": "55b35562c0a8010e01cff22378e0aea9"
      },
      "delivery_plan": "",
      "impact": "3",
      "active": "false",
      "work_notes_list": "",
      "business_service": "",
      "priority": "4",
      "sys_domain_path": "/",
      "time_worked": "",
      "expected_start": "",
      "rejection_goto": "",
      "opened_at": "2016-01-19 04:49:47",
      "business_duration": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "group_list": "",
      "work_end": "",
      "approval_set": "",
      "wf_activity": "",
      "work_notes": "",
      "short_description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "correlation_display": "",
      "delivery_task": "",
      "work_start": "",
      "assignment_group": "",
      "additional_assignee_list": "",
      "description": "Switch occasionally drops connections",
      "calendar_duration": "1970-01-01 00:02:17",
      "close_notes": "updated firmware",
      "sys_class_name": "problem",
      "closed_by": "",
      "follow_up": "",
      "sys_id": "04ce72c9c0a8016600b5b7f75ac67b5b",
      "contact_type": "phone",
      "urgency": "3",
      "company": "",
      "reassignment_count": "",
      "activity_due": "",
      "assigned_to": "",
      "comments": "",
      "approval": "not requested",
      "sla_due": "",
      "comments_and_work_notes": "",
      "due_date": "",
      "sys_mod_count": "1",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "escalation": "0",
      "upon_approval": "proceed",
      "correlation_id": "",
      "location": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

***result*** field contains array of elements, and that elements can be different depending from API consumed.

For more info about that API is [Table API](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/orlando/rest/c_TableAPI) from ServiceNow Product.

As you can see on documentation, API path is something like this: GET /now/table/{tableName}, where tableName could be different values and result elements tipology will depend from table fetched.

So the response elements inside result field can be formed with different name or different quantity of attributes. Basically it's a database exposed through HTTP, so every table could be formed with different number of columns.

My GET Implementation:

```java
public Mono<Result> get(){
    return client.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path(this.tablePath)
                    .queryParam("active", "true")
                    .queryParam("state", "1")
                    .build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Result.class);
}
```

POJOs

```java
@Data
public class ProjectTask {

    private String project;

}
```

```java
@Data
public class Result <T> {

    List<T> result;

}
```

Simple Usage to get the error:

```java
List<ProjectTask> projectTasks = Objects.requireNonNull(
        client.table("pm_project_task")
                .get().block())
        .getResult();

for (ProjectTask task : projectTasks){
    System.out.println("========PROJECT=============== "+task.getProject());
}
```

My runtime error at line `for (ProjectTask task : projectTasks){`

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to my.namespace.api.services.servicenow.model.ProjectTask
```

Response Needs:

- Result POJO has to use Generic Type to manage different response elements type.
- If first point cannot be accomplished try to give a solution to fetch that API  with a reusable GET implementation for different table types.
- I don't want to return a List from my client, my idea is that this library only return Mono or Flux objects.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **parameterizedtypereference** to deserialize the json to the exact type of `Result`. Else Spring deserializes any unknown type to *LinkedHashMap*.
eg.

```
  public Mono<Result<ProjectTask>> get(){
    return client.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path(this.tablePath)
            .queryParam("active", "true")
            .queryParam("state", "1")
            .build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Result<ProjectTask>>() {
        });
  }
```

And if you want to make this method `get` a generic one, that will work for all types of `Result`, then you should look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter).

Comment: Run on my side, also with generic proposal on link provided, to be precise, on call section, is need it to declare a variable to get the Mono<T> value and after call getResult() on initialization of another variable of type List<ProjectTask>, otherwise get a compilation error  because List<Object> is expected instead of List<ProjectTask>. Maybe we could improve this but I don't know how.

Comment: I've unset acceptance check, Is not possible for the moment use linked solution.
Make a list with more than one class in ParameterizedTypeReference extension throw a java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)


enhancement on Spring Framework project
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20643

Comment: @OscarRP If there is some issue with generics and parameterizedtypereference, i would suggest you to use inheritance. Have Projecttask and other pojos inherit a common parent class and use that in your webclient response.