# SpringBoot ; Casting problem when sending post request to another sevice with RestTemplate() like ResponseEntity<SomeObject<DtoObject>>

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, casting, resttemplate

I am using a RestResponse class that I writed .   I am using this class in each service and also Dto class, but I coulnd't get my dto data correctly. Data is in RestResponse class but it is always responding with LinkedHashMap . Data is coming in LinkedHashMap I need to cast it to my Dto data

```
ResponseEntity<RestResponse> result;
result = (new RestTemplate()).postForEntity(uri, requestBody, RestResponse.class);
```

But I need the result as `ResponseEntity<RestResponse<SomeDto>>`.
Is there any way to fix this.

When I debug it . Data object seems LinkedHashMap. But in the other service I am using `ResponseEntity<RestResponse<SomeDto>>` for response.All classes are same in each service.

This is my RestResponse class:

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private T data;
    private String titleLanguageKey;
    private String title;
    private String messageLanguageKey;
    private String message;
    private ResponseTypeEnum type;

    public RestResponse() {}

    public RestResponse(T data, ResponseTypeEnum type) {
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public RestResponse(String messageLanguageKey, String message, ResponseTypeEnum type) {
        this.title = "";
        this.titleLanguageKey = "";
        this.message = message;
        this.messageLanguageKey = messageLanguageKey;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public RestResponse(String titleLanguageKey, String title, String messageLanguageKey, String message, ResponseTypeEnum type) {
        this.title = title;
        this.titleLanguageKey = titleLanguageKey;
        this.message = message;
        this.messageLanguageKey = messageLanguageKey;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public RestResponse(T data, String titleLanguageKey, String title, String messageLanguageKey, String message, ResponseTypeEnum type) {
        this.data = data;
        this.title = title;
        this.titleLanguageKey = titleLanguageKey;
        this.message = message;
        this.messageLanguageKey = messageLanguageKey;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference`, you can take a look there for more information [resttemplate with generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter)