# Passing a generic Type as responseType in RestTemplate.exchange() in Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, generics, resttemplate, type-erasure

I have a candy factory that exposed various endpoints to get candies in a bag.

candy such as

1. name: m&m ; endpoint: candy-factory/mnms
2. name: skittle; endpoint: candy-factory/skittles
3. name: smarties; endpoint: candy-factory/smarties

Api response pattern is below

```
 public class CandyWrapper <T> {
  @JsonProperty("candies")
  private List<T> candies;
}
```

I have a generic service class which deals with getting the candies using Spring RestTemplate

```
public class CandyStore<T> {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  private final Class<CandyWrapper<T>> type

  String candyFactroyUrl;

  
  public CandyStore(Class<CandyWrapper<T>> type, RestTemplate restTemplate, String 
   factoryUrl) {
    this.type = type;
    ....
    ....
   }

  public CandyWrapper<T> getCandies(){
      
       HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> request = new HttpEntity<>();
       ResponseEntity<CandyWrapper<T>> response;
       response = restTemplate.exchange(candyFactroyUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, type);
       
       return response.getBody();
   }

}
```

Now when I am going to configure the CandyStore service with the actual type of the Candy ; Unable to determine the candy type to pass in the service constructor.

```
@Bean()
public getSkittleCandyStore(RestTemplate restTemplate, String skittleUrl){

  //TODO
   get the class of type CandyWrapper<Skittle> so that I can pass it to the service 
   constructor. 
   
   CandyWrapper<Skittle> instance = new CandyWrapper<Skittle>();

   // instance.getClass() does not give the class conforming to the parameter below.
  return new CandyStore(???, restTemplate, skittleUrl);

}
```

Any help to clear up the generics concepts is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics undergo type erasure, meaning they don't retain their generic type at runtime, so `CandyWrapper<Skittle>.class` just wont' work.

You may try to use `ParameterizedTypeReference` from Spring instead, which provides an abstract class that you simply subclass to capture the generic type, like:

```java
@Bean
public CandyStore<Skittle> getSkittleCandyStore(
    RestTemplate restTemplate,
    String skittleUrl
) {
    return new CandyStore<>(
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<CandyWrapper<Skittle>>() {},
        restTemplate,
        skittleUrl
    );
}
```

and `CandyStore`:

```java
public class CandyStore<T> {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ParameterizedTypeReference<CandyWrapper<T>> typeRef;
    String candyFactroyUrl;

    public CandyStore(ParameterizedTypeReference<CandyWrapper<T>> typeRef, RestTemplate restTemplate, String factoryUrl) {
        this.typeRef = typeRef;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.candyFactroyUrl = factoryUrl;
    }

    public CandyWrapper<T> getCandies(){
        HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> request = new HttpEntity<>();
        ResponseEntity<CandyWrapper<T>> response;
        response = restTemplate.exchange(candyFactroyUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, typeRef);
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

so please, make sure to update the `restTemplate.exchange` to use the new `typeRef` field instead, should looks like:

```java
response = restTemplate.exchange(candyFactroyUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, typeRef);
```

Read more about `ParameterizedTypeReference`:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html
- [Using Spring RestTemplate in generic method with generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter)

Comment: Thank you Yahor for taking the time to respond. Your solution worked. I actually missed that, RestTemplate has an exchange method with ParameterizedTypeReference.