# Generic restTemplateExchange with generic responseType

Tags: java, http, types, casting

I would like to create a own generic method that calls the *restTemplate.exchange*.
In particular I would like that the signature of this generic method to be :

```
protected <T> ResponseEntity<T> genericExchange(String uri, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, -->responseType<--)
```

I would differentiate what *exchange* method call according to "responseType"

- if *responseType* is *Class< T>* I call * exchange(URI url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class< T> responseType)*
- if *responseType* is *ParameterizedTypeReference< T>* I call *    exchange(URI url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference< T> responseType)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer, and it was working for me:

[Unable to get a generic ResponseEntity<T> where T is a generic class "SomeClass<SomeGenericType>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819734/unable-to-get-a-generic-responseentityt-where-t-is-a-generic-class-someclass)

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.exchange(pUrl, HttpMethod.POST, pEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResultListPage<MyObject>>() {});
```